# Getting Axios error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I have my django-rest-framework api running on port 80000. and my react project on port 3000. I have installed cors-headers in django and am making requests to api successfully, but there is one problem:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants';

export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);

  dispatch({
    type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
    payload: {
      product: data.id,
      name: data.name,
      image: data.image,
      price: data.price,
      countInStock: data.count_in_stock,
      qty,
    },
  });

  localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
```

so axios should be making request to get product data from `/api/products/${id}` this url and then update state in redux store which i'm calling in useEffect in CartPage component like this:

```
const CartPage = () => {
  const productId = useParams()
  const location = useLocation().search
  const qty = location ? Number(location.split("=")[1]) : 1
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    if(productId) {
      dispatch(addToCart(productId, qty))
    }
  }, [dispatch, productId, qty])
  
  return (
    <div>Cart</div>
  )
}

export default CartPage
```

but there is an axios error which says
GET [http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/[object%20Object]](http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/%5Bobject%20Object%5D) 500 (Internal Server Error)

why am i getting this? and what is this object thing at the end after products/.
anny feedback would be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: `useParams` returns an object of key/value pairs of URL parameters. Chance are you want to `const { productId } = useParams()`

Comment: thanks for pointing at  the right direction, actually what i needed was: 
const productId = useParams().id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just miss one thing which needs to fix like this:

```
const { id } = useParams(); // you will get your product id like this
```

const productId = useParams() returns object that's why you get 500.